# What RepositoryItem a should use to select "ImageId" field from entity list?

Tags: c#, image, grid, devexpress

I use RepositoryItemLookUpEdit to display FullName field (string) in grid's cell.

```
  _entityReferenceEditor = new RepositoryItemLookUpEdit
  {
    AllowNullInput = DefaultBoolean.True,
    NullText = NullValueText,
    DataSource = typeof( Entity ),
    DisplayMember = MemberHelper.GetProperty( ( Entity e ) => e.FullName ).Name,
    ValueMember = MemberHelper.GetProperty( ( Entity e ) => e.Id ).Name,
    ShowHeader = false
  };
```

But I can't show Image field (System.Drawing.Image) instead of FullName field.

Unfortunately RepositoryItemImageComboBox doesn't have ValueMember and DisplayMember to show Image field but save ImageId field.

The second optional question. Image field is byte[]. It means this field I have to convert from byte[] to System.Drawing.Image (via MemoryStream).

Comment: For the second question I can use Adaptor which will convert byte[] fields to Image fields.

Comment: Try using the GridLookUpEdit control You'll have a drop-down list that is capable of displaying a preview image.